# Android/AOSP: Fun & Qs about the "missing ranchu kernel"

Tags: android, android-source

After I built Android  from AOSP source the [official guide](http://source.android.com/source/building.html#emulate-an-android-device) suggests that launching `emulator` is all one needs to do. Sadly that does not work for me...
(I am building for Nexus 7 "deb", Android Studio is not involved, not even present on this very machine.)

```
emulator: ERROR: bad workspace: cannot find prebuilt ranchu kernel in: ~/aosp/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/ranchu/kernel-qemu
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (~/aosp/sdk) but cannot find kernel file in ~/aosp/sdk/system-images/ sub directories
```

**Is my `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` set properly?** One would guess it should be `~/aosp/sdk`, but apparently the emulator expects `system-images` right under `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/`. My `system-images` resides in `~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools` though.
When I change it to `~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools` it still isn't good enough:

```
...
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools) but cannot find kernel file in ~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/ sub directories
```

But there are actually several `kernel-ranchu` files in those subdirectories:

```
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/android-tv/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/default/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/google_apis/armeabi-v7a/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-25/android-tv/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-25/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-25/android-wear/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/kernel-ranchu
~/aosp/prebuilts/devtools/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86_64/kernel-ranchu
```

**Which one is the correct one and how do I deliver it to the emulator?**
I tried several `-kernel <kernel>` but either I got a fatal memory error (for the x86_64-based ones) or I get an emulator with black screen and a popup saying that emulator based based on x86 would be much faster (with the google_apis/armeabi-v7a.) I waited tens of minutes for the last one, nothing happens, still the black screen, not even "android" logo. Maybe because in the middle of the output there is following message:

```
ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8
```

...strangely the process is not terminated, not sure how fatal the error is then.

Comment: Run emulator with the -verbose flag and post all your output. It should provide more insight on the files it is looking at to start the emulator.

Comment: It seems that not all targets are supposed to be run within the emulator. After days of struggling with aosp_deb-userdebug and -eng I tried full-eng and that one works as charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that only small subset of targets is intended to run in the emulator. Those with specific device in their name ("deb") are not blessed.

After days of struggling with aosp_deb-userdebug and -eng I tried `full-eng` and that one works as charm.

Answer (score 0):

Select your CPU/ABI to Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64) when create the simulator AVD